# Out of memory running correlation analysis in Julia

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, correlation

I have a large sparse matrix in Julia which I want to run correlation analysis on but I encountered the:

`ERROR: OutOfMemoryError()`

My sparse matrix details are:

`200833×200833 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 209018611 stored entries:`

I ran the `cor()` command on the sparsematrix but I wasn't able to get my result according to the error above.

What can I do to get my results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `cor` function calculates correlation for each pair of columns (or rows depending on the `dim` parameter).
Since you have 200k columns your correlation matrix would have a size of 320GB.

Now, assuming that you have enough computational power to handle such task, your best bet is to perform computations pairwise and store the results to a file.

Assuming your `s` is your sparse matrix:

```
for (i,j) in Iterators.product(1:size(s,2),1:size(s,2))
     if (i<j)
         cor_v = cor(@view(s[:,i]), @view(s[:,j]))
         #TODO save it somewhere since you have a total of 320 GB of data!
     end
end
```

Since it is a big computational task probably you will be using a `@distributed` macro to distribute it over your cluster but that is a separate topic.

Comment: Thanks! do I need to save the ```cor_v``` as the clusters work on them or write it when it has finished computing?

Comment: there are many patterns to do that depending on your cluster configuration or factors such as persistence of your nodes (ie. if you use AWS Spot or GCE Preemtible instances). Usually it is good to design your computation in such a way that the data is stored every 5 or 10 minutes by every working process. I usually use AWS for computations and S3 for the storage.For some inspiration you can look at https://github.com/pszufe/KissCluster or post different questions on StackOverflow.